# VB.Net doesn't allowing inline initialization of list

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create list of object using inline code.

```
Dim lstPopupProps As New List(Of Object)(New Object() With {.Name = "", .Age = 20})
```

but I am getting an error

> Object initializer object cannot be use to initialize an instance of System.Object

Is there any way to create list of object like this or I will have to add objects one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for list initializers in VB.NET is `From {…}` and the syntax for anonymous types is `New With`:

```
Dim lstPopupProps As New List(Of Object) From {
    New With {.Name = "", .Age = 20}
}
```